# Why wont it align?

Tags: css, html

[My problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqlfq.png)

Here is my code. I have just put it all in as I don't know where the problem lays; I know where it should,
Sorry if this is wrong of me.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Custom styles
  ========================================
*/

body {
  background: #130b3d;
  color: #888;
  font: 300 16px/22px"Century Gothic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Grid
  ========================================
*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 960px;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.grid,
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.container,
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Clearfix
  ========================================
*/

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Rows
  ========================================
*/

.row {
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 960px;
  padding: 0;
}
.row,
.row-alt {
  min-width: 100%;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Typography
  ========================================
*/

h1,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: #7b7b7b;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 900;
}
cite,
em {
  font-style: italic;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Buttons
  ========================================
*/

.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.btn-alt {
  border: 1px solid #dfe2e5;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Home
  ========================================
*/

.hero {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 18px 60px 46px 60px;
}
.hero h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.teaser img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Primary header
  ========================================
*/

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}
.tagline {
  text-align: center;
}
.primary-nav {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.primary-header a,
.primary-footer a {
  color: #fff;
}
.primary-header a:hover,
.primary-footer a:hover {
  color: #cdcdcd;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Primary footer
  ========================================
*/

.primary-footer small {
  text-align: left;
}
.primary-footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Links
  ========================================
*/

a:hover {
  color: #cdcdcd;
}
a {
  color: #7b7b7b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*
  =======================================
  Navigation
  =======================================
*/

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
/*
  =======================================
  Aside
  =======================================
*/

.aside {
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.form {
  float: right;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
form {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  font: 300 16px/22px"Century Gothic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.form-style label {
  color: #7b7b7b;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-style input,
.form-style textarea {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 3.5px;
  color: #888;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.form-style input,
.form-style textarea {
  width: 250px;
}
.form-style textarea {
  height: 78px;
}
.form h3 {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.aside h3 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.aside img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 47%
}
/*
  ==========================================
  About
  ==========================================
*/

.about {
  margin: 30px 30px 50px 30px;
}
.history {
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-right: 55px;
}
.about h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.about h5 {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.about h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.about img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 12.5%
}
.about-img {
  margin-left: 155px;
}
/*
  ===============================
  Contact
  ===============================
*/

}
.map {
  margin-bottom: 33px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Event Technologies Ltd.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheet/main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>

  <header class="primary-header container group">
    <h1 class="logo">
     <a href="home.html">Event Technologies</a>
      </h1>
    <h5 class="tagline">
     Interactive Event Multimedia
   </h5>

    <nav class="primary-nav nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="vacancies.html">Vacancies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <aside class="aside">
    <h3>Our clients include:</h3>
    <img src="assets/images/home/virgin_logo.png">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/willow_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/hsbc_logo.jpg">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/home_office_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/land_rover_logo.png">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/nissan_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/jaguar.gif">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/capita_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/cancer_logo.png">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/legion.gif">
  </aside>


  <aside class="form">
    <h3>Make an Enquiry</h3>
    <fieldset class="form-style">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name" required>
      </label>
      <!--
   -->
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
      </label>
      <!--
   -->
      <label>
        Company:
        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company" required>
      </label>
      <!--
   -->
      <label>
        Enquiry:
        <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  </aside>

  <section class="row">
    <div class="hero grid">
      <section class="teaser col-1-3">
        <h3>
          <a href="services.html">Interactive iPads
        </h3>
        <img src="assets/images/home/interactive.png">
        </a>
        <h5>Real-time audience feedback tools</h5>
      </section>
      <!--
      -->
      <section class="teaser col-1-3">
        <h3>
            <a href="services.html">Interactive Fundraising
          </h3>
        <img src="assets/images/home/fundraising.jpg">
        </a>
        <h5>Maximise revenue potential at fundraising events</h5>
      </section>
      <!--
        -->
      <section class="teaser col-1-3">
        <h3>
               <a href="services.html">Bespoke Development
                </h3>
        <img src="assets/images/home/bespoke.jpg">
        </a>
        <h5>Not looking for an off-the-shelf solution? No problem...</h5>
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="primary-footer container group">
    <nav class="primary-nav nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="vacancies.html">Vacancies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <h5>Event Technologies Ltd.<br> Unit 10 Rotherbrook Court,<br> Bedford Road,<br> Petersfield,<br> GU32 3QG</h5>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

(I understand if you want to vomit over it, still learning)

I just don't understand why it won't align with the other two. From my point-of-view, I can't see any differences.

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: It's not clear from your question what elements are supposed to be aligned. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: "intercative Ipads" takes one line in your example. Have you tried some other text (that takes two lines like the others)?

Comment: "I have just put it all in as I don't know where the problem lays", if that's the case then I'm sorry to break it to you but [PEBKAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error). Please review how to create a [mcve] and update your post accordingly.

Comment: definitely humor error!

Answer (score 0):

```
.hero .teaser h3 { min-height: 64px; }
```

Adjust the pixels so it fits.

Comment: Alignment is not recommended to be done using px as this will cause problems on different devices / screens

Comment: too true - thats not recommended either :) using em and % really help with flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Try add float to your sections. Don't forget it clear:both.

```
float:left
```

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Custom styles
  ========================================
*/

body {
  background: #130b3d;
  color: #888;
  font: 300 16px/22px"Century Gothic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Grid
  ========================================
*/

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 960px;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
  float:left;
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.grid,
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.container,
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Clearfix
  ========================================
*/

.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Rows
  ========================================
*/

.row {
  background: #fff;
  min-width: 960px;
  padding: 0;
}
.row,
.row-alt {
  min-width: 100%;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Typography
  ========================================
*/

h1,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: #7b7b7b;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 46px;
  line-height: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 900;
}
cite,
em {
  font-style: italic;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Buttons
  ========================================
*/

.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.btn-alt {
  border: 1px solid #dfe2e5;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Home
  ========================================
*/

.hero {
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 18px 60px 46px 60px;
}
.hero h3 {
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #7b7b7b;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.teaser img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Primary header
  ========================================
*/

.logo {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}
.tagline {
  text-align: center;
}
.primary-nav {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.primary-header a,
.primary-footer a {
  color: #fff;
}
.primary-header a:hover,
.primary-footer a:hover {
  color: #cdcdcd;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Primary footer
  ========================================
*/

.primary-footer small {
  text-align: left;
}
.primary-footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
/*
  ========================================
  Links
  ========================================
*/

a:hover {
  color: #cdcdcd;
}
a {
  color: #7b7b7b;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*
  =======================================
  Navigation
  =======================================
*/

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.nav li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
/*
  =======================================
  Aside
  =======================================
*/

.aside {
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.form {
  float: right;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
form {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
input,
select,
textarea {
  font: 300 16px/22px"Century Gothic", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.form-style label {
  color: #7b7b7b;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.form-style input,
.form-style textarea {
  border: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-radius: 3.5px;
  color: #888;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
.form-style input,
.form-style textarea {
  width: 250px;
}
.form-style textarea {
  height: 78px;
}
.form h3 {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.aside h3 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.aside img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 47%
}
/*
  ==========================================
  About
  ==========================================
*/

.about {
  margin: 30px 30px 50px 30px;
}
.history {
  margin-left: 55px;
  margin-right: 55px;
}
.about h4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.about h5 {
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.about h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
.about img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 12.5%
}
.about-img {
  margin-left: 155px;
}
/*
  ===============================
  Contact
  ===============================
*/

}
.map {
  margin-bottom: 33px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Event Technologies Ltd.</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/stylesheet/main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>

  <header class="primary-header container group">
    <h1 class="logo">
     <a href="home.html">Event Technologies</a>
      </h1>
    <h5 class="tagline">
     Interactive Event Multimedia
   </h5>

    <nav class="primary-nav nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="vacancies.html">Vacancies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <aside class="aside">
    <h3>Our clients include:</h3>
    <img src="assets/images/home/virgin_logo.png">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/willow_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/hsbc_logo.jpg">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/home_office_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/land_rover_logo.png">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/nissan_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/jaguar.gif">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/capita_logo.jpg">
    <img src="assets/images/home/cancer_logo.png">
    <!--
    -->
    <img src="assets/images/home/legion.gif">
  </aside>


  <aside class="form">
    <h3>Make an Enquiry</h3>
    <fieldset class="form-style">
      <label>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full name" required>
      </label>
      <!--
   -->
      <label>
        Email:
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
      </label>
      <!--
   -->
      <label>
        Company:
        <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company" required>
      </label>
      <!--
   -->
      <label>
        Enquiry:
        <textarea name="comments"></textarea>
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
  </aside>

  <section class="row">
    <div class="hero grid">
      <section class="teaser col-1-3">
        <h3>
          <a href="services.html">Interactive iPads
        </h3>
        <img src="assets/images/home/interactive.png">
        </a>
        <h5>Real-time audience feedback tools</h5>
      </section>
      <!--
      -->
      <section class="teaser col-1-3">
        <h3>
            <a href="services.html">Interactive Fundraising
          </h3>
        <img src="assets/images/home/fundraising.jpg">
        </a>
        <h5>Maximise revenue potential at fundraising events</h5>
      </section>
      <!--
        -->
      <section class="teaser col-1-3">
        <h3>
               <a href="services.html">Bespoke Development
                </h3>
        <img src="assets/images/home/bespoke.jpg">
        </a>
        <h5>Not looking for an off-the-shelf solution? No problem...</h5>
      </section>
      <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <footer class="primary-footer container group">
    <nav class="primary-nav nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <!--
    -->
        <li><a href="vacancies.html">Vacancies</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <h5>Event Technologies Ltd.<br> Unit 10 Rotherbrook Court,<br> Bedford Road,<br> Petersfield,<br> GU32 3QG</h5>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you have a single line of text heading the first picture, and 2 lines for the other 2 pics. That's why it's not aligning.
Now, how to get it to be aligned? Few solutions available, my suggestion would be to switch your grid into a table and call it a day (since you're doing it for learning). So your view would be a 3x3 table with the headings in the first row, pictures in the second row, and description comes third.

Also, since you're learning, I highly recommend switching to a framework like Bootstrap to do the work for you. It's easy to use and easy to learn.

Best of luck

Comment: It was indeed this! I didn't notice it earlier, but through many changes, must've removed something somewhere.

Comment: That always happens. Something trivial slips along the way of development :D

Answer (score 0):

I presume the example is a screenshot taken from the site - is it possible to have the url to really see what is going on.
Otherwise it might be better to begin from a new markup and gradually add to it.
And please do not use tables - you will be learning a deprecated way.

css

```
div.rowcontainer{
}
div.rowitemcontainer{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
div.rowitem{
    margin:1em;
}
```

HTML (put directly under `<body>` tag so there is no influence from other elements)

```
<div class='rowcontainer'>
    <div class='rowitemcontainer'>
        <div class='rowitem'>
            Item<br />1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='rowitemcontainer'>
        <div class='rowitem'>
            I am<br />Item<br />2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='rowitemcontainer'>
        <div class='rowitem'>
            This<br />is<br />Item<br />3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```